# Query on custom drupal 7 field

Tags: 7, database

I'm facing problem in Drupal query for order by custom field
Here is my query

```
$result = db_query('SELECT n.nid FROM {node} n WHERE n.type = :ntype', array(':ntype' => 'portfolio'));
```

this work fine but when I change that to this

```
$result = db_query('SELECT n.nid FROM {node} n WHERE n.type = :ntype order by n.field_weight DESC', array(':ntype' => 'portfolio'));
```

That query not working. It saying field not found?

Comment: Because field weight is a field's property, not found in node table at all?

Comment: yes you are right how to access it in order by

Comment: Found the answer by searching here. Actually the customs are placed in separate table and that why we have to query two tables. Thanks for all who helped.

Comment: does it produce any result in your query engine? seems to have an error there- for such a query.

Comment: No i didnt use that query in query engine i write it in php file and execute it. Also that will not work as i mentioned have to join the custom field table to get required results.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like (supposing "weight" module is used and weights are stored in the "weight_weights" table - to be adapted for another module ) :

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n', array('nid', 'type'));
$query->join('weight_weights', 'w', 'n.nid = w.entity_id');//join can not be chained
$query->condition('n.type', 'portfolio', '=');
$query ->orderBy('w.weight', 'ASC');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = db_select('node', 'n')
                ->fields('n', array('nid','type','field_weight'))
                ->condition('n.type', 'portfolio', '=')
                ->orderBy('n.field_weight','DESC')                  
                ->execute();
```

You can use this code.

Comment: I tried your code it gives me that error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'n.field_weight' in 'order clause': SELECT n.nid AS nid FROM {node} n WHERE (n.type = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ORDER BY n.field_weight DESC; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => portfolio )

Comment: Then I think it is not query problem.It may be a database problem.May be the name of the field is wrong.Please check that first.

Comment: Or use only the field name in where condition.`field_weight` instead of `n.field_weight`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i tired both ways i checked the field its correct name and i use it without n and still getting that error :(

Comment: please check the query in your sql query editor.If it give you error on the query editor.Then surely it is a database error.